# Need advice on a web service "request template" pattern

Tags: c#, web-services, design-patterns, soap

We are designing a system which needs to allow the construction of objects made up of data, sourced from disparate datasources (databases, and back office systems for example) and are looking at ways to facilitate this functionality across a web service interface.

To service this requirement we propose creating a "request" object as an input parameter for the web service request methods so the web service knows which fields on the object to populate from which source, a sort of "pick n mix" to poulate your return object.

How could this "Request template" object be designed and is it a suitable approach?

We need the solution to achieve the following:

- Must be clear to the consumer of the
  service what the method expects and
  what will be returned.
- The Consumer must have visibility as 
  to what locations are available for
  each field when constructing the
  request.
- A clear relationship between the
  response object and the request
  object exists.

Comment: Personally I despise this approach, but that is just a personal opinion.

Comment: Don't try to stuff every possible functionality into one function. If you have several sources then create several functions.

Comment: @leppie are you able to give reasons for your stance?

Comment: @Adam Naylor: No objective reasons. I just dont like it. To me it seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @leppie: Any suggestions to alternative approaches would be gratefully recieved

Comment: Sound like you are heading into the ESB. 'Messages' represent the requests & responses. You can have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus to see if this would fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using WCF and have the request object use an interface, that way it is extensible as well?

Comment: I will take a look at what WCF can offer but one of the goals is for the interface to be cross platform.  The design of the request object, is my concern and using an interface I assume would aid solving that design issue, but I'm not sure how as yet.